# JPA more instances than desired

Tags: java, jpa

I have a class called `NodeType` backed using JPA by a SQL Server database.

Nothing special there, no relations, just some fields. There are even more of them, but for simplification I've omit them:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="node_type")
@NamedQuery(name="NodeType.findAll", query="SELECT n FROM NodeType n")
public class NodeType implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public NodeType() {
    }

    public int getId() {
            return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
            return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }

}
```

When starting up my application, I read them and put them all into a `HashMap`, taking the property `name` as key to find it easier later.

In the database, there are currently five items.

```
id  name       maxNoExits  mandatoryExits  defaultExits
==  =========  ==========  ==============  ============
1   NTYPE_HUP  0           NodeHangup
2   NTYPE_ANN  1           NodeAnnounce
3   NTYPE_SLP  1           NodeWait
4   NTYPE_XFR  0           NodeTransfer
5   NTYPE_TBR  32          NodeTimebased
```

Somewhen later, and I don't know where exactly this happens, multiple instances for each item suddenly exist (3 instances per item currently)

Example: In the application, I have an instance of NodeType with the values

```
1   NTYPE_HUP  0           NodeHangup
```

The eclipse debugger tells me that:

- In my map, there actually **is** an item having the same values as the mentioned instance above
- `map.get` returns `null` for this instance
- 15 instances exist for the class `NodeType`
- for each line in the database, always three instances seem to exist.
- comparing all the fields, they seem to be equal. Even the `id` for the strings seem to be the same ones. Shouldn't `getHash()` return the same and `equals()` should return `true` then?

The last point shocks me as I'm not instanciating them anywhere in my application! Does anybody know when this happens?

If JPA uses a cache (does it?), it should look previously created items up using the `@Id` column. Even though I'm doing more than one `createQuery`, they should all refer to the same items. Or am I wrong?

It's all quite strange for me and I don't know how to debug it.

I hope someone can bring some light in the dark.

**Edit:** All I can tell is that these 15 instances exist as soon as I use the corresponding JPA request for the first time. Placing a debugger trap in the constructor, I can confirm that all instances are created right one after the other.

**Edit2:** For the fun and the sake of testing, I just tried to work it around reimplementing `hashCode()` (simply `return this.id;`) and overriding `equals()` (`return this.id == other.id;`)

The 15 instances are still there. As I'm only reading, I currently don't care about it as I can now consider all the three instances as an equal item. But it's not the solution to the base problem. I suspect this might happen elsewhere, too - without having tested.

Comment: The answer is probably no, but just to make sure. Are you merging entities? Merge returns new object. What is you JPA implementation?

Comment: No I don't. And as I said: I start the application up, do some unrelated stuff, then execute some kind of findAll-query and tadaa, I have all the instances. No merging, not eveng calling `persist()` at this point. I'm not adding anything to this table anyway in the code.

Comment: Ah and my implementation is EclipseLink.

Comment: Where do you have the duplication? In the map? If yes, what are the map keys than? Is it `Map<String, NodeType>` with 'name' of `NodeType` as a key? or is it `Map<NodeType, Somethiong>` ?

Comment: No. I just found that there exists a duplication using this map. The map is of type `Map<String, NodeType>` actually referencing the `NodeType` instance by its name using this map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you have 5 tuples in the database, 5 different instances in the map (given that the names are uniques ?) and 15 different instances loaded by JPA, which are equals by groups of 3...

I guess this is a problem of [Cache Level](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Caching_Overview).

It is possible that EclipseLink creates different equal instances for a same tuple while reading if the loaded instances are stored in the Persistence Context Cache - Level 2 (i.e. the EntityManager) - and not the Persistence Unit Cache - Level 1 (i.e. the EntityManagerFactory) . You probably use a different EntityManager for each read operation. In such a case, EclipseLink can not find the previously cached entity.

This depends on your application configuration. The problem could also be caused by a memory lack and a weak reference cache. Further explanation is available in the [EclipseLink cache documentations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching) page.